# Is it possible to "Pre-render" a collapsibletree Shiny object with ~4000 nodes for end users?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing a shinyapp that involves displaying the company's managerial hierarchy.

Once uploaded to a remote server, it takes approximately 10-15 minutes for the app to completely render and become interactive for the end user.

Is it possible to keep the app "loaded" on the remote server so that end users have a significantly reduced load time?

My own searching suggests the solution is to keep `renderCollapsibleTree` in `global.R` and have the server run a session continuously (still need to figure out how to do that).

If there is a simpler solution, I'd love to hear it.

Edit: I've included my `global.R` code:

```
tree_data <- read.csv("FileName", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
                    select(EmployeeName, SupervisorName, pathString) 


hierarchy_tree <- data.tree::as.Node(tree_data, pathDelimiter = "/")

rendered.tree <- renderCollapsibleTree({
  collapsibleTree(hierarchy_tree, inputId = "node")
})
```

and relevant part in my `server.R` code:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  output$tree <- rendered.tree
}
```